# Linq to SQL bulkupdate from 2 different databases, 2 different tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Hello i'm using linq and sql to create a windows serrvice that updates some rows if there was a change in the table in the last 5 minutes so far this is what i have:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
namespace Prueba
 {
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
         int tienda = 9;

        var conex = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        try
        {
            var source =
                new SqlConnection(
                    "Server=LAPTOP-VCD9V9KH\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=backoffice;User Id=sa; Password=root;");

            var destination =
                new SqlConnection(
                    "Server=LAPTOP-VCD9V9KH\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Corporativo_PRB;User Id=sa; Password=root;");
            source.Open();
            destination.Open();
            source.CreateCommand();
            var infoExistenciases = conex.Info_Existencias.Where(x => x.FechAct > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5));

            foreach (var x in infoExistenciases)
            {

                var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
                    "update Info_Corp_Existencias set Existencia =" + x.Existencia + " where sku ='" + x.SKU + "'" +
                    "AND Tienda =" + tienda, destination);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            source.Close();
            destination.Close();
            Console.Beep();
        }
        catch
            (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadLine();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

So far this code updates everything in the destination server but i can't really really pinpoint down how to put everything into a temp table to let linq update it foreach argument.

Thank you for your time

Comment: So instead of running one update-statement, you want to use linq and execute an update-statement for every row?

Comment: Yes, currently it does that for each statement but i need to generate something in bulk to use only one connection to the database instead of using the foreach property.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in two different tables, it's difficult to select the corresponding row in the second table without knowing the table design exactly. But you can probably do something like this:

```
var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(
                "update Info_Corp_Existencias set Existencia = (select field FROM Info_Existencias WHERE id=@otherid where sku ='" + x.SKU + "'" +
                "AND Tienda =" + tienda, destination);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So leave out the foreach statement and just launch ONE update statement to the database that will update every row's field by using a subselect to get the correct value from the row.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly removing the statement from the foreach removes the relation with x , this is the relation i have with my tables. I'm doing it in a testing enviorement before doing it in the windows service.

While my current script updates if the table was modified in the last 5 minutes it does it row by row. I kinda need it to make a bulkupdate instead.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's why I suggest using a subquery. Is it possible to select the right row from the second table in the subquery?